# не приходят и не списываются деньги в бд, как исправить?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

````
    uid = message.from_user.id
    words = message.text.split()
    card_p = words[0]
    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (uid,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        new_2 = row[3] - int(words[1])
        cur.execute("""UPDATE users SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?""", (new_2, uid))
        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE card = ?""", (card_p,))
        results = cur.fetchall()
        for i in results:
            bot.send_message(uid, f"✅ Перевод успешно выполнен!\n\nСумма: {words[1]}$\nПолучатель: @{i[1]}")

    cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE card = ?""", (card_p,))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        new_3 = row[3] + int(words[1])
        cur.execute("""UPDATE users SET balance = ? WHERE card = ?""", (new_3, card_p))
        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE card = ?""", (card_p, ))
        results = cur.fetchall()
        for i in results:
            id_p = row[0]
            cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?""", (uid,))
            result = cur.fetchall()
            for w in result:
                bot.send_message(id_p, f" Уведомление о поступлении денег\n\nСумма: {words[1]}$\nОтправитель: @{w[1]}")```
````

Comment: А коммитить не нужно после апдейтов? Или у вас автокоммит включен?